# Count all unique customers in date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big spreadsheet with order data. And I have a column containing the "customers first order date" (lets call it column A), and then I have "order data" (lets call it column B).

What I want to achieve is something like this - except the comparison of col A and col B doesn't work in COUNTIFS, and I can't get my head around how I could solve it:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20000;"="&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$20000;Sheet!$A$2:$A$20000;">="&Sheet2!E$2;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$20000;"<="&Sheet2!E$3))
```

Is there a way to do this with countifs?

My data could be something like:

| Col A | Col B | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 00:01:00 | 01-01-2021 00:01:00 | 1 |
| 01-01-2021 00:01:00 | 05-01-2021 20:11:33 | 1 |
| 01-04-2021 00:01:00 | 01-04-2021 00:01:00 | 3 |
| 01-03-2021 00:01:00 | 01-03-2021 00:01:00 | 2 |
| 01-04-2021 00:01:00 | 24-04-2021 17:51:29 | 3 |
| 01-04-2021 00:01:00 | 01-05-2021 19:55:59 | 3 |
| 01-04-2021 00:01:00 | 04-06-2021 04:22:01 | 3 |
| 01-04-2021 00:01:00 | 24-06-2021 18:09:44 | 3 |
| 29-04-2021 00:01:00 | 04-06-2021 04:22:01 | 4 |
| 29-04-2021 00:01:00 | 24-06-2021 18:09:44 | 4 |

With this data, what I would expect from the forumula - if the start and end dates are in march - I want "1", since that is the amount of the unique IDs with col A date in the range. If it is in january, I altso want "1", since that is the amount of unique ID's with dates in column A that matches the range.
And if it is april, I want "2", since that is again the amount of IDs in the range.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Can you use dynamic arrays?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Latest through Office365 for Windows :)
It is for a cohort analysis.

Comment: Look into `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, should make this relatively straightforward

Comment: If you would mock a small example of the data and expected out put it will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mathieu helped me out. So this is what seems to do the job:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A20000;(Sheet1!C2:C20000>=Sheet2!$E$2)*(Sheet1!C2:C20000<=Sheet2!$E$3);"")))
```